# VB.NET - Does this code execute the ThreadPool correctly?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Code:

```
'Get the Thread Count - Lets say this value was 150;
Dim threads As Integer = CheckerThreads.Value

'Set the Thread Count;
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(threads, threads)
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(threads, threads)
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = threads
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True

'For Each proxy from the Opened File;
For Each Proxy In proxies

    'Check the Proxy;
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New WaitCallback(AddressOf CheckProxy), Proxy)

Next
```

The code above, Takes Each Proxy from a `List()` and simply uses a WebRequest to check the proxy, But thats not related, What i'm wondering is using a `For Each` the way I have, is it executing like I think it is, Or have I done something wrong?

Which of the following is happening?:

**1 - Is 1 proxy being checked with 150 processes?**

-or-

**2 - Is it checking 1 proxy per process with 150 processing checking at the same time?**

If it's doing **#1** then how can I resolve it to do **#2**?

Comment: There's an easy way to answer your own question. Do something other than check a proxy, e.g. write a number to the console, and see whether you get the same number 150 times or 150 different numbers. Also, have you read the documentation for the `Set` methods you're calling?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Good idea about the console, But no ide what you mean by "Set" methods.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Ok, Tested it and its doing #2, But like, bit confused, is it actually executing at the same time or after one finishes?

Comment: By "`Set` methods" I mean the methods whose names begin with "Set".

Comment: The tasks assigned to your threads will be executed over the same time frame.  I say it that way because the only way that two tasks can actually be processed at exactly the same time is by multiple processor cores.  Obviously you don't have 150 processor cores so 150 tasks can't be processed at the same time.  They will be interleaved though so, because processors work so fast, it appears to the naked eye that they are processed simultaneously.

Comment: The reason I suggested that you read the relevant documentation is that messing with the thread counts can actually hurt performance. With so many threads active you can cause things to slow down because of all the context switching.  It's generally best to just queue everything up and let the system handle the rest, as the documentation says.

Comment: @jmcilhinney you should put that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tasks assigned to your threads will be executed over the same time frame. I say it that way because the only way that two tasks can actually be processed at exactly the same time is by multiple processor cores. Obviously you don't have 150 processor cores so 150 tasks can't be processed at the same time. They will be interleaved though so, because processors work so fast, it appears to the naked eye that they are processed simultaneously.

The reason I suggested that you read the relevant documentation is that messing with the thread counts can actually hurt performance. With so many threads active you can cause things to slow down because of all the context switching. It's generally best to just queue everything up and let the system handle the rest, as the documentation says.

Comment: Thanks! So my loop is set to execute and check all the proxies as fast as possible perfect. And yes I know setting the Processing Thread Count it can negate performance which is why I have the value of the count hooked up to a UpDownNumericalValue or whatever its called. So if the user finds the threads to be too much they can lower it or higher it even. Thanks